# Merge "university" and "college" tags

Tags: discussion, tags

Look at [university](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/university) and [college](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/college). They are about the same topic. Should they be merged?

Comment: Which one should "win"? :-) Maybe we can have a poll via two competing answers..

Comment: @GS-ApologisetoMonica I've written an answer in favor of "university". :-)

Comment: Sounds good - if someone wants to argue for "college" they can post an answer.

Comment: Other tags should also be considered for merging with these: [tag:school], [tag:education], [tag:education-savings], [tag:tuition]

Answer (score 9):

On one hand, [college](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/college) has more questions than [university](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/university). 97 questions vs. 12 questions.

On the other hand:

- Few countries use "college" to refer to "university" (most notably the US). In most countries, colleges either do not have degree-awarding powers, are merely high schools, or are part of universities.
- In any case, when speaking to a global audience, "college" is ambiguous whereas "university" is less so.

Therefore, I suggest that [university](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/university) wins.

---

Further reading:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/College
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/University

Answer (score 3):

The underlying problem is that most questions originate in the US, where "college" and "university" have the same meaning.

The secondary problem (a very common one on SE sites) is the poor tag data:

- [college](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/college): *Questions related to saving and paying for a college education*
- [university](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/university): [ empty ]

possibly because "college" can be used in different ways in different countries.

---

But both tags are far too specific for the questions being asked.

When one is saving for or paying off one's educational expenses, does it really matter what specific kind of institution it is?

Perhaps *both* tags should be replaced by:

- [education](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/education): *Questions related to saving and paying for post-secondary education*

Comment: I think "education" might be misused for educational materials about investing.

Comment: There's a tag for `education-savings`

Comment: [tag:education] is already a tag, and should probably also be merged with the other ones.

Comment: +1 for "education".  I think that [tag:college], [tag:university], [tag:education-savings], [tag:school], and [tag:tuition] should all be merged into this.